# Determining differentiability of functions in a system of linear equations in Problem 2-15(c) in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: calculus, matrices, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have some questions about problem 2-15 (c) in Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*:

> **Problem 2-15(c).** If $\det(a_{ij}(t) \neq 0$ for all $t$ and $b_1,\dots,b_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable, let $s_1,\dots,s_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the functions such that $s_1(t),\dots,s_n(t)$ are the solutions of the equations
>   $$
> \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ji}(t) s_j(t) = b_i(t) \qquad i = 1,\dots,n.
> $$
>   Show that $s_i$ is differentiable and find ${s_i}'(t)$.

My questions are:

1) If the functions $a_{ij}(t)$ are not differentiable, isn't it possible that the functions $s_i(t)$ are not differentiable (since the problem doesn't require anything of the functions $a_{ij}(t)$)? For instance, if $a(t)=|t|$ and $s(t)=|t|$, then $a(t)s(t)$ is differentiable at $0$ even though neither $a$ nor $s$ is.

2) Why is the sum labelled $\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ji}(t)s_j(t)=b_i(t)$ instead of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}(t)s_i(t)=b_j(t)$? Is $a_{ji}$ supposed to be any different from $a_{ij}$ when both $i$ and $j$ range from $1$ to $n$?

3) In general, if $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, are there necessary and sufficient conditions on a function $g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (that is not everywhere differentiable) such that $fg$ is differentiable?

Comment: From the way this is stated, it sounds like the $a_{ij}$ were introduced earlier in the problem. I am guessing that there are additional conditions on them that you haven't included here.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to your first question.**

The $a_{ij}$'s appearing in Problem 2-15(c) are to be assumed to be differentiable, because this is a continuation of Problem 2-15(b), where the $a_{ij}$'s are introduced and defined to be differentiable.

---

**Answer to your second question.**

The sum could very well have been labelled in the other manner you suggest. It is a matter of taste which one you prefer.

---

**Answer to your third question.**

Given $f$ differentiable, for $fg$ to be differentiable it is sufficient (but not necessary) to assume that $g$ is differentiable. To see that it is not necessary, take $f$ to be a constant function and $g$ to be any non-differentiable function. Then $fg$ is differentiable if $f = 0$ but not otherwise.

I doubt that there is any single criterion that can be both necessary and sufficient for your question.